# Understanding proof that sequence $x_n =( -1)^{n}$ is not convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

To Understanding proof that sequence $x_n =( -1)^{n}$ is not convergent .

Here goes the proof :-

Firstly i assume that sequence converges to x .i.e -1 and 1 lies between $x$-$\epsilon$ and $x+$$\epsilon$ . The length of interval is $2 \epsilon$ which is greater than $2$ (as can be seen by drawing number line ) . so this happens for $\epsilon$ greater than 1 .Because since $2\epsilon$ can only accommodate -1 and 1 if it is greater than 2 i.e if epsilon is greater than 1 .How do i deal with other case when epsilon is less than 1

Thanks

Comment: This reminds me of a joke..."let $\epsilon$ be less than 0".

Comment: It is easy to conclude that this sequence is not a Cauchy sequence. Hence it is not convergent.

Comment: Have you learned about Cauchy sequences yet?

Comment: @Sloan not yet ,no

Comment: I gave a strong hint.  The case when $\epsilon<1$ should be the easier case to prove--and you really don't need cases... just make $\epsilon$ very small.

Comment: @TravisJ is my proof for $\epsilon$ greater than 1 correct ?

Comment: @K.Dutta, I think your approach is slightly in the wrong direction.  If you assume that $x_n\to x$ then you want to show that $x$ cannot simultaneously be close (within $\epsilon$) to $-1$ and $+1$.  You really only want (ever) take $\epsilon$ to be very, very small positive number.  Keep in mind that if you assume $x_n\to x$ then you must arrive at a contradiction to be successful.  If you say "if $\epsilon$ is big enough, then we're ok" that's not a contradiction.  You want to say if $\epsilon$ is ... then we have a problem (contradiction).

Comment: @TaylorTed there are two distinct accumulation points, while a convergent sequence only has one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of a limit is that for **any** $\epsilon>0$ there exists an $N$ so that if $n\geq N$ then $|x_{n}-x|<\epsilon$.  Now, you just need to argue that if $|-1 - x|<\epsilon$ then $|1-x|>\epsilon$ which is a contradiction (to the assumption that $x_n\to x$).  Take $\epsilon$ as small as lets you make your argument (smaller than $1$).

Comment: if mod of -1 -x is less than $\epsilon$ ,then how is mod 1 -x less than $\epsilon$

Comment: @K.Dutta, If $|-1-x|<\epsilon$ then $|1-x|>\epsilon$ is the point... we don't want both to be smaller than $\epsilon$ (that's how we get the contradiction).

Comment: How come "$|-1 - x|<\epsilon$ then $|1-x|>\epsilon$"? All I can come up with is $|1 + x|<\epsilon$.

Comment: @Tim, it helps to think of what $|-1-x|$ means... it is the distance from $x$ to $-1$.  If that distance is small, then $x$ cannot also be close to $1$.  And, $|1-x|$ is the distance from $x$ to $1$.  Basically, all this is saying is that you cannot be simultaneously close to $1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore tha case $\epsilon>1$ right away. Convergence says that for *every* $\epsilon>0$ we have $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ for all $n>n_0$ (with $n_0$ dependig on $\epsilon$). Specifically, it should hold for $\epsilon=\frac1{42}$. Since it doesn't, we do not have convergence.